# how to take a char value from user in kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, char

I want to take a Char value from the user but .toChar does not compile in my code

```
fun main (args:Array<String>){
    var character:Char= readLine()!!.toChar()
    println("your value is $character")
}
```

```
Error:(4, 38) Kotlin: Unresolved reference: toChar
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which char do you want?

This will return the first char of the String, since a String is essentially a CharArray.

```
fun main (args:Array<String>){
    val character = readLine()!![0]
    println("your value is $character")
}
```